# How does keypress events works with element which doesn't take any focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I need to attach a key press event on a

element. I know we can use $(":li").live() will do that but since li is not a focusable element how can it take the key press event. Or when does the key press event gets fired for this elements?

Please help?

Comment: You need a focusable element for keypress binding, also live is deprecated, use `on` instead

Answer (score 0):

An unfocusable element will not fire key events (although key events may bubble up from focusable elements contained within it).

If you want to make the element focusable and receive key events, you could set its `tabindex`, either as an attribute in HTML or via JavaScript. Setting a tabindex value of 0 puts the element in the default tab order, which is the order elements appear in the DOM.

```
<li tabindex="0">...</li>
```

To set all `<li>` elements as focusable in jQuery:

```
$("li").prop("tabIndex", 0);
```